# How do I get the Hotkeys working on a Lenovo IdeaPad?

Tags: lenovo, ideapad

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my U400 Lenovo,  I found some hotkeys are not working( enable/disable touchpad, display on/off, webcam enable/disable )

How to fix the problem?

Comment: I am using Idepad Z370 and have the same problem. Lenovo support pages says there is no Linux driver yet.

Comment: I have experience with that, but for me only display was important and what I did is that I wrote small bash script `#!/bin/sh;xset dpms force off`(use enter instead of ;) and in Keyboard->Shortcuts->Own shortcuts I create new event and set this script to run when pressing on some button

Answer (score 2):

A useful hotkeys trouble shooting page worth looking at is: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting