# Lenovo hotkeys not working

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Z570 IdeaPad laptop with Kubuntu 14.04 installed.It has 5 touch hotkeys.Among them 3 are for controlling volume(mute,decrease and increase).They works fine.But the other two are not working.One is used to switch the display mode while watching images or videos and another is for controlling fan speed and thermal dissipation.There is a programme for windows called onekey theater to control the first key.And lenovo energy management controlls the second one.But lenovo energy management is also not usable.

Comment: maybe you could have a look at the answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/153403/231418

Comment: Thank You.But I am sorry to say that my problem is another one.Its the two touch keys.Others are working fine.